# iTunes 10.2.x will not upgrade on Windows 7 Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, updates

I am unable to update iTunes on Win7, either by running the Update, or going to the Tools->Download Only and running the Setup from there.  The only way to update currently is to do a complete uninstall, reboot, followed by a fresh install.

Are there known issues with the iTunes updater and Win7?  Is there any way to get the update to work?